# How do I compare a dayname to a date and get a date to compare with it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

part of the query checks I need to have is if it's Monday is the first working day of the month, return the date 3 days back, otherwise take it as it is. I came up with this piece of code, but for some reason it's not working. Any suggestions?

```
RequestDate >= CASE WHEN(DATENAME(dw,DAY(@st)) like 'MONDAY') AND 
         (((Day(@st) = 01)) OR ((Day(@st) = 02)) OR ((Day(@st) = 03)))
        THEN dateadd(d,-3,@st) 
        ELSE @st END
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server, postgresql, mysql, etc?

Comment: `x like 'foo'` is pointless. without wildcards, `like` is functionally identical to `x = 'foo'`

Comment: Is this a bug in the question? "DATENAME(dw,DAY(@st)" that probably should not have the day function

Comment: It seems DATENAME function returns 'Monday', with only first letter capitalized, depending upon other settings

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not using day-of-week names and using day-of-week values instead:

```
DECLARE @st DATETIME
SET @st = '06/01/2015'

SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN
      DATEPART( DW, @st ) = 2 AND
      DATEPART( D, @st ) < 4
    THEN
      DATEADD( D, -3, @st )
    ELSE 
      @st
  END AS RequestDate
```

Comment: This is returns a date that is not even a monday, but it gave me an idea on how to do it thanks! What I am looking for is to see if any of the first 3 days of a month are a Monday.